# Detect closed TCP connection during write with boost::asio immediately

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I have a TCP-server with multiple clients/sessions. Each session has its own thread for receiving data from the client, but there is only one thread ("writeThread") to respond to all clients.

Now there is the problem, if a client closes the connection during the "writeThread" is writing to this socket it takes multiple seconds until the write operation notices that the connection is closed remotely. Sometimes its not notices at all, just when I send a `signal` for an installed sighandler manually, the application will detect it and break the write operation.

The time is measuared between `Logger::trace("start write");` and `Logger::trace("remote term, closed socket ");`

Despite the fact that this may not the best design, is there a possibility to detect the closed connection immediately, or do I really have to redesign?

```
bool myWrite(UINT8 *pu8_buffer, UINT32 u32_size)
{
    bool b_success = false;
    try
    {
        Logger::trace("start write");
        b_success = (u32_size == boost::asio::write(_x_socket, boost::asio::buffer(pu8_buffer, u32_size)))
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error &er)
    {
        if (er.code() == boost::asio::error::eof || 
            er.code() == boost::asio::error::connection_reset)
        {
            boost::system::error_code x_er;
            _x_socket.close(x_er);
            if (!x_er)
            {
                Logger::trace("remote term, closed socket ");
            }
            else
            {
                Logger::err("remote term, closed socket failed");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        Logger::err("write exception\n\t",ex.what());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        Logger::err("write unknown exception",(uint32_t)this);
    }
    return b_success;
}
```

Comment: There is a option in TCP/IP to decrease the timeout period (the time it takes for one end to notice that the other is no longer there).  However as TCP/IP is a reliable and robust connection protocol (and uses this time to retry the packets that have not yet been acknowledged) decreasing the timeout can introduce other problems (eg spurious disconnects).  If the "other-end" closes the socket correctly you will get immediately notified, if however the other-end just stops responding (or there are other connection problems) then this time-out occurs.

Comment: @RichardCritten Are you sure that this is because of a too "large" tcp window size?

Comment: No not without a packet trace - it's just the low-hanging option.  Get wireshark or an equivalent and look at the packets on the wire and see if there had been a clean shutdown or just a timeout.

Comment: @RichardCritten you're right, as soon there is an RST-ACK on the wire the write function will be aborted immediately. So a part of my problem/situation is on the other side -- thanks for that. Can you tell me some more about that "low-hanging" option? Can this timeout be set from the application or is it an TCP internal? Maybe you have some useful link.

Comment: You don't specify the platform, so here is the Microsoft answer (similar on other platforms) you probably want the `SO_SNDTIMEO` option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The platform is linux and windows, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use asychronous write operations, it is possible to multiplex writes on the same thread without one blocking the other. You can even do the same for reads.

Comment: Good idea, but using `async_write` I have a design issue, since my calling thread always allocates the the buffer and frees it after writing. As `async_write` returns immediately the buffer may be freed before copying to kernel buffer. If I would copy the buffer to local send buffer in `mySocket`, this buffer would be overwritten in the next `mySocket::myWrite()` call. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Free the buffer in the write callback

Comment: That's correct, but is there any possibility to pass the buffer pointer, which was used to the callback, to know which buffer to free?

Comment: std::function is your friend. You include the pointer in the function object either using std::bind or a lamda.

Comment: Absolutely right, this should work out. I'll try tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question I will summarize "Richard Critten"s comments.

The issue was that there was no graceful disconnect from the client connected to my server. If there is a proper disconnect the write function will break immediately. To avoid long term or infinite blocking of the write operation its possible to configure a timeout for how long a write operation can take before reporting an error. This timeout can be set with the `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket option. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html